# Django debug toolbar 1.8 offline mode

Tags: python, jquery, django, offline, django-debug-toolbar

I started using django debug toolbar 1.8 in a project with django 1.11.17, everything goes well until I tried to use it from home (is not showing at all) where I don't have internet, that is the only difference I can think of. Any ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is what I have found out, django debug toolbar 1.8 still depends on jquery and is trying to get it from ajax.googleapis.com so that's where the problem is.

Reading the docs on https://django-debug-toolbar.readthedocs.io/en/latest/changes.html#id19 I learn that since django debug toolbar 1.2, jquery is not bundled on the code

> 1.2 (2014-04-25)
>
> New features
>
> ```
> The JQUERY_URL setting defines where the toolbar loads jQuery from.
> ```

Current value in the code:

```
'JQUERY_URL': '//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.2.4/jquery.min.js'
```

**Solution:**

> 1. Download a copy of jquery and serve it locally

Download the contents
   https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.2.4/jquery.min.js and save
   it on a file named **jquery-2.2.4.min.js**. Open a terminal in the
   folder where the file is and run:

For python 2.x

```
python -m SimpleHTTPServer 2000
```

For python 3.x

```
python -m http.server 2000
```

> 2. Configure your project to work offline

Put this on settings.py

```
DEBUG_TOOLBAR_CONFIG = {
 'JQUERY_URL': '//localhost:2000/jquery-2.2.4.min.js'
}
```

Just run your server and start debugging!!!